# Protractor - Wait for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to wait for multiple elements on the page, I don't know how many there could be but there will be at least one. I understand waiting for a single element using the following, which works fine.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css("h3[title='Test Form']"))), 10000);
    expect(element(by.css("h3[title='Test Form']")).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

I wanted to change this slightly to wait for multiple elements and so tried the below (adding .all to element).

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element.all(by.css("h3[title='Test Form']"))), 10000);
    expect(element.all(by.css("h3[title='Test Form']")).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

Unfortunately when I try this I get

```
Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

p.s. Newbie to Protracor and its quirks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`presenceOf`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) expects a *single element* (`ElementFinder`) to be passed in.

You would need a *custom Expected Condition* to wait for. If I understand you correctly, you need to wait until N elements are present. Here is how you can do it:

```
function waitForCount (elementArrayFinder, expectedCount) {
    return function () {
        return elementArrayFinder.count().then(function (actualCount) {
            return expectedCount === actualCount;  // or <= instead of ===, depending on the use case
        });
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
var forms = element.all(by.css("h3[title='Test Form']"));
browser.wait(waitForCount(forms, 5), 10000);
```

Comment: Many thanks. I actually went about it a slightly different way as I do not know how many element there could be, only that there will be one. I will use the above I am sure in the future and so has save me asking another question!